# Wordpress Post Content Display

Tags: posts

In my post page,
used gallery on post plugin to display images , 
while i m trying to retrieve the post content -used the_content , 
but showing the plugin images also. how i get text editor content only?

Comment: ok can you explain this a little better? 
you can use the global $post object in the loop to get the content...

Answer (score -1):

use this code to show only content of post

```
    $args = array(
    'order'    => 'ASC'
);
query_posts( $args );

while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
// get only post of content not work plug-in short code
$post_7 = get_post(get_the_ID()); 
echo $title = $post_7->post_content;

endwhile;

// Reset Query
wp_reset_query();
```

Comment: Never ever use `query_posts`. It is really a bad function to use as it breaks many stuff on a page which is vital for plugins and other functions

Comment: If you write reset query end of the statement then it works perfectly.

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: An explanation to what your code does and how it works would increase the value of your answer. Dumping code like this does not make for a good answer. Please file an [edit] with the required info. Thank you :-)